# Visual Studio 2012 css color picker missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I seem to be missing Visual Studio 2012's color picker feature in the css editor. It only shows a drop down menu.

I've tried changing the color picker option in preferences. Also tried resetting settings.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

Type # after the property:

```
color:#
```

With Resharper installed, I need to click `Ctrl J`.

That gives you the first bit of the drop down (some swatches).  You then click the double arrow pointing down to get the color picker proper.

Answer (score 8):

Are you typing the pound "#" sign? That's what triggers the nice color picker.

(eg, "color:#" when you press "#" you get the picker, otherwise you just get crappy dropdown).

Comment: The dropdown gives you color names, the color picker gives you numeric RGBA values.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have any extensions installed? ReSharper in particular? I was experiencing the same problem, and thought that ReSharper might've been the cause. Uninstalled it, and now I have the CSS color picker as advertised. If you don't have ReSharper installed, it may be caused by another extension.